# The instance member 'user' can't be accessed in an initializer. (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I wrote this code:

```
 class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;

  MainScreen({Key? key, required this.user}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<MainScreen> {
  late User user;
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final screens = [
    HomeScreen(user: user),
    Map(),
    Photo(),
    Notifications(),
    Profile()
  ];
}
```

But trying to pass user as parameter to HomeScreen gives this error:

> The instance member 'user' can't be accessed in an initializer.  Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

How can I solve?

If it can be useful, the other part of the code is:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: screens[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        initialActiveIndex: 2,
        items: const [
          TabItem(icon: Icons.home,title: 'Home'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.map, title: 'Map'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.photo_camera_rounded, title: 'Photo'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.notifications, title: 'Notification'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.account_circle_rounded, title: 'Profile'),
        ],
        onTap: (index) => setState(() {
          currentIndex = index;
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this it will solve your problem:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screens = [
      HomeScreen(user: user),
      Map(),
      Photo(),
      Notifications(),
      Profile()
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: screens[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        initialActiveIndex: 2,
        items: const [
          TabItem(icon: Icons.home,title: 'Home'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.map, title: 'Map'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.photo_camera_rounded, title: 'Photo'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.notifications, title: 'Notification'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.account_circle_rounded, title: 'Profile'),
        ],
        onTap: (index) => setState(() {
          currentIndex = index;
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The problem with your code is you are not having the access to the user before the initState is executed.